# Delete MS Word-Object in Dataview with ArcPy (ArcMap)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-frame, element, ole

My mxd has a dataframe which contains a MS Word-Object ("Insert" - "Object").
The Object was added to data view.

I want to access the MXD dataframe in PyScripter using

```
arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dataFrames'
```

I'd also like to import the MXD to ArcGIS Pro but it doesn't work, I get an error.

When I delete the Word-Object all these errors do not occur.

(Note: When I use the Python window in ArcMap, the AttributeError does not occur. However, I would like to make it work in PyScripter)

I thought about deleting the Word-Object with ArcPy, is that possible? I have hundreds of MXDs with this Word-Object, so I need to automate this.

I already tried using ListLayoutElements but nothing is returned because the object was added in data view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think arcpy exposes any methods that allow you to delete OLE objects inserted into a data frame.  You can automate this using ArcObjects.

So in screen shot below I have a polyline layer, graphic and an OLE word document in a map view (so NOT layout).

[image: Screen shot]

The following VBA code will find any OLE frame and delete it:

```vba
Sub test()
    ' This code demonstrates how to find OLE Frames in map and delete them
    ' This code does not save the map to make changes permanent use IApplication to do that
    '
    ' Duncan Hornby, 19/12/2023
    
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument
    
    Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
    Set pActiveView = pMXD.ActiveView
    
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pActiveView.FocusMap
    
    Dim pGraphicsLayer As IGraphicsLayer
    Set pGraphicsLayer = pMap.ActiveGraphicsLayer
    
    Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
    Set pGraphicsContainer = pGraphicsLayer
    pGraphicsContainer.Reset
    
    Dim pElementProp As IElementProperties
    Dim pElement As IElement
    Dim pOLEFrame As IOleFrame
    
    ' Step through elements in map
    Set pElement = pGraphicsContainer.Next()
    Do Until pElement Is Nothing
        Set pElementProp = pElement
        If pElementProp.Type = "OLE Frame" Then
            ' Found an OLE Frame, now delete it
            Set pOLEFrame = pElement
            pGraphicsContainer.DeleteElement pOLEFrame
        End If
        Set pElement = pGraphicsContainer.Next()
    Loop
    
    ' Refresh map
    pActiveView.Refresh
End Sub
```

You can run this directly inside the VBA editor in ArcMap, or you now have the basic template of code to convert this into VB.Net and run it as outside ArcMap, your choice.

After running this code we see only the Word OLE element has been removed.

[image: Gone]

Comment: I doubt many users will have VBA in ArcMap after it went out of support at 10.2.2. VB.Net would be fine though.

Comment: @Berend, yes indeed! I do feel like I'm part of a rapidly vanishing subset of users! The king is dead (VBA) long live the King (Python)!  I tend to use VBA  to answer such questions as firing up Visual Studio is too much when trying to demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Despite VBA being "dead"... this is a great answer! Proof that nothing truly dies if it's loved. Well, maybe love is too strong a word here....

Comment: @Hornbydd thank you this helps a lot!

Comment: I'd like to run this code for hundreds of MXDs. The MXD paths are stored in a txt file. In python i would loop over the txt file, could I do the same in VBA? Also, should i do this in the ArcMap VBA Editor (i thought about downgrading ArcMap to an earlier Version) or rather in VB.net using VSCode? I am completely new to ArcObjects and VBA programming.

Comment: You could certainly automate it in VBA reading from a text file., but as @Berend points out you need to install the VBA environment which is not installed by default anymore, you would also need the install file, esri don't provide that anymore and a license file. So only option is VB.net. You could create a console app or a button that you drop into arcmap and that could provide a nice interface to help automate. Take note of [which version of VS you need](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm).

Comment: Be aware ESRI have withdrawn development and no doubt support for ArcMap in the near future, so you are flogging a dead horse if your organisation wants to continue using Arcmap. You should seriously consider migrating to ArcPro, that is the future ESRI have envisaged.

Comment: You could of cause approach GIS developers, such as myself and others on this platform and pay for a solution, e.g. development of an AddIn for ArcMap. Depends how bad your organisation needs the removal of an OLE frame from the maps in an essentially dead piece of software that will almost certainly be defunct in a couple of years... food for thought!

Comment: Thank you again for your help. We are actually preparing to migrate to ArcGIS Pro. However, you cannot import a mxd to ArcGIS Pro when there's a Word OLE present in the data view. Seems like a bug.